# How to move an image on a touch in windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I am able to use pinch Zoom in and Zoom out an image which i take in a canvas. but i also want movement of image on a single finger touch for pinch Zoom functionality i have to touch with both fingers. i use manipulation delta for Zoom.Can anyone Please Suggest

```
private void OnManipulationDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.X > 0.0 && e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.Y > 0.0)
    {
        // Scale in the X direction
        double tmp = PenguinTransform.ScaleX * e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.X;

        if (tmp < 1.0)
            tmp = 1.0;
        else if (tmp > 4.0)
            tmp = 4.0;

        PenguinTransform.ScaleX = tmp;

        // Scale in the Y direction
        tmp = PenguinTransform.ScaleY * e.DeltaManipulation.Scale.Y;

        if (tmp < 1.0)
           tmp = 1.0;
        else if (tmp > 4.0)
           tmp = 4.0;

        PenguinTransform.ScaleY = tmp;               
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the Hold event to define that the image is ready to be moved, and then using the manipulation events to control the movement of the image.  I have explained this approach in more detail on a different SO thread. Please find it here [Windows phone 8 drag and drop grid in grid by user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627720/windows-phone-8-drag-and-drop-grid-in-grid-by-user/24629656#24629656).

Hope this helps.