# How add drag&drop items in Windows Phone silverlight app?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, drag-and-drop, windows-phone-8.1, telerik

I have old app creted in Windows Phone Silverlight 8.0. I use RadDataBoundListBox  (Telerik Controls)  for list in app. I need add drag&drop function in my app.But it was not easy.

1. RadDataBoundListBox do not support drag&drop.
2. In Silverlight 8.0 work with drag&drop difficult and complex.It is only [example drag&drop](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2012/06/27/a-gesture-driven-windows-phone-todo-application-part-two-drag-re-ordering.html) for list in WP Silverlight. But it does not suit me.
3. I can upgrade app to Wimndows Phone Silverlight 8.1. But ListView  is not available for WP Silverlight 8.1.  Which control should I choose for drag&drop and reorder?

I have a time limit. Please tell me the fast way to solve this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drag and drop from list to canvas on windows phone with MVVM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22859855/drag-and-drop-from-list-to-canvas-on-windows-phone-with-mvvm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend ListBox, reorder can easily be done using linq extension.

If you have an extremely large list you should be careful with listbox.

for drag and drop look at [Drag and drop from list to canvas on windows phone with MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22859855/drag-and-drop-from-list-to-canvas-on-windows-phone-with-mvvm)

Comment: It is very intresting.  Have you example code (Drag and drop from list to canvas)?

Comment: @FetFrumos what do you want to drag ? The code is basicly to tap into the events, then add the element upon manipulationstarted to a canvas you bring to the front. Then you can change the position of the element in the canvas. When manipulationended you delete the element from the canvas and remove the canvas, and then add the deleted element to the UiElement you want it dragged to ;) hope that helps a bit. If you can be more precise I could add some more code, but it will probably first be next week. I have some releases to come this week.

Comment: I want to drag items from one ListBox to another ListBox. I decided to upgrade the project to the Windows Phone 8.1 RT.

Comment: this is not exactly, but very close

Answer (score 0):

Look at [drag and drop in windows phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18691754/drag-and-drop-in-windows-phone) and https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pakistan/2013/07/10/drag-drop-in-silverlight-for-windows-phone/

Answer (score 0):

I searched for information about it for two days. Add full drag&drop for items in windows phone silverligth - It is inpossible. May be used reorder. It is a [great control](http://reorderlistbox.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest) for wp silverligth(only reorder). I will update the project to windows phone 8.1.